# How to set UNIQUE constraint to multiple columns MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
table location_category {
    id,
    location_id,
    category_id,
    is_primary
}
```

What I want is to set a UNIQUE constraint for the combination location_id and is_primary.
I get that using this will make a multi column UNIQUE constraint

```
ALTER TABLE `votes` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`location_id`, `is_primary`);
```

But my concern is that we can have multiple categories for a location but only set 1 category as primary.
For example:

```
| id | location_id | category_id | is_primary |
| 1  |      1      |      1      |      0     |
| 2  |      1      |      2      |      0     |
| 3  |      1      |      3      |      1     |
| 4  |      1      |      4      |      0     |
```

Will this violate the UNIQUE contraint? Since I have multiple instances of location_id = 1 and is_primary = 0?

Just trying to figure this out. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Set `is_primary` to not 0/1 but NULL/1.

Comment: or add category_id  to the unique

Comment: @Akina you should make that an answer, with some explanation.  though a trigger may be a better answer for this class of problem.

Comment: @nbk looks to me like that would defeat the purpose of the unique index

Comment: @Akina so what data type should I set is_primary to? Can I still set it to tinyint? Can I update tinyint to accept NULL whenever I update  another category to primary?

Comment: @ysth *though a trigger may be a better answer for this class of problem.* No. The best solution is either NULLability or generated column. Trigger is worse than these 2 solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to change anything, UNIQUE allows multiple  NULL values

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `votes` (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `location_id` INTEGER,
>   `category_id` INTEGER,
>   `is_primary` INTEGER
> );
>
> ALTER TABLE `votes` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`location_id`, `is_primary`);
>
> INSERT INTO `votes`
>   (`id`, `location_id`, `category_id`, `is_primary`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1', '1', NULL),
>   ('2', '1', '2', NULL),
>   ('3', '1', '3', '1'),
>   ('4', '1', '4', NULL);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * from `votes`
> ```
>
> ```
> id | location_id | category_id | is_primary
> -: | ----------: | ----------: | ---------:
>  1 |           1 |           1 |       null
>  2 |           1 |           2 |       null
>  3 |           1 |           3 |          1
>  4 |           1 |           4 |       null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e47765d0af7f497094c1215cabf5c51b)*

So you can only have one location with is primary 1

Comment: I see. How about when I select another category as the primary, say I select category_id 1 as the primary, does MySQL allow updating INTEGER with NULL?

Comment: @Paul yes, but you have to set current primary category's is_primary to null before setting the new one to 1 (though it can be in the same update statement, e.g. `update votes set is_primary=if(category_id=2,1,null) where location_id=1 order by is_primary desc`)

Comment: though with all of this, you would be better off with a separate location_primary_category table with just a unique location_id and a category_id indicating the primary category for the location